# Finding an atlas of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to understand the concept of atlas of a manifold. In particular, I would like to know how do you find an atlas of a given manifold, this isn't very clear to me since the only example that I've seen is the following.

Consider $$ f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$  $$f(x) = \frac{x_1^2}{r_1^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{r_2^2} -a$$

We define $M_a = \{x \in \mathbb{R^2}: f(x) = 0\} $ and we find that it is a manifold for $a>0$.

At this point the exercise asked to define an atlas for such manifold and the given solution was the following.

Define $$\phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^2}$$  $$\phi(\alpha)=(r_1cos(\alpha),r_2sin(\alpha)).$$ Let $U_1 =]0;\frac{3}{2}\pi[$ , $U_2 = ]\pi; \frac{5}{2}\pi[$ and set $V_i = \phi(U_i), i = 1, 2$.

Now we define $\phi_i: U_i \rightarrow V_i$ by $\phi|_{U_i}$, hence an atlas for $M_a$ is given by $$\mathcal{A} = \{(U_1,\phi_1,V_1),(U_2, \phi_2, V_2)\}$$

Can someone please explain these steps, for example how all these intervals and immersions were found? If someone has other examples of similar exercises it would be very nice to see them because I'd like to understand.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be $x\in\Bbb R^2$ for the points of $M_a$, and I guess there should be a $\pi$ in interval $U_1$. These are two intervals that together cover the whole circle (ellipse). Locally (=when we restrict to one of the two given charts) both arcs of the circle is homeomorphic to an open line segment.